# Store Static Data in DB or Spring yml Property File

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, yaml

I have some static configurations that will not be changed for each environment, for example, the mapping between client names and their id. In this case, should I store them in a Spring yml property file or in a database, eg. mongoDB, so that they can be easily accessed via Java code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the one side, consider that when you are adding a database component, you are adding additional potential point of failure to your app. What will happen if DB will not be accessible, for any reason ? ( crashed, under maintenance, network issues ) ?

From the second side, it depends how exactly your implementation will be using files. For example, if you will be adding items in your mapping between clients/ids, will you need to restart/rebuild/redeploy your app? How many running instances of your app will you have?

So, there are no one exact answer for all cases

Answer (score 1):

It better keep in spring yaml instead of storing in any Database. Because calling the IO operations little expensive . Keeping static code in yaml or properties file will faster to access.